# Writing a function that combines two nodes in a linked list together

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have written a function in my memory manager program that looks at a linked list, and tests if the nodes are physically next to each other byte wise, and then merges them together as one if they are. It is possible that the node physically next to a free node is currently holding memory, in which case it wont be merged. I'm having trouble figuring out how to get this to work, I keep either getting endless loops or no merge.

```
void IfFreeTogether(void)
{
    FREEPTR l =freelist;
    FREEPTR f = freelist;
    FREEPTR g = f->next;
    int i = 0;
    while(l!=NULL)
    {

        if(f->start_byte-1 == g->end_byte)
        {       
            g->size = g->size + f-> size;
            g->end_byte = f-> end_byte;
            g->next = f->next;

            l=g->next;
        }

        if(f->end_byte+1 == g->start_byte)
        {
            f->size = f->size + g-> size;
            f->end_byte = g-> end_byte;
            f->next = g->next;

            l=f->next;
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: don't call a possibliy mutating function `checkIf`. it's misleading.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will rename it.

Comment: It is better to clean empty elements of structure after merge to avoid problems in the future (for example, in the first 'if' section it is better to set f->size = 0; f->start_byte = 0; etc after merge). After it you'll see, that you get access to zeroed values on the next iteration after any merge. So just correct both f and g values after merge.

Comment: Where do you use i ? And maybe adding else between the two ifs will avoid some problems.

Comment: Perhaps I missed it in the details written, though I've read them a few times now. if nodes are to be combined, will the be *guaranteed* contiguous in the list? I.e. `a-->b-->c-->nil`, where warranted, `a` and `b` might be combined, or `b` and `c`, or even all three, but never `a` and `c`. Is that correct ?

Comment: I think you are right as long as we dont have (a&b)&c or a&(b&c), which will combine a and c.

Answer (score 1):

From the code snippet you posted it seems that `l` is the only var being assigned new values in the loop, but `f` and `g` are the only ones being read (in spite of the fact they're initialized only once and never changed after).

This means you're not making any change to the list. Worse - since `l` only gets assigned by `g` or `f`, you actually don't even advance `l` anywhere new, leading probably to an infinite loop (except for the corner case where you actually manage to merge the entire list)